# Issue with Dynamic Import of .png files in Remix V2 (remix-run / react)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, remix.run

I am working on a ReactJS project using Remix V2 (`remix-run`) and facing an issue while trying to dynamically import `.png` images from a local directory based on a variable value.
I've tried using both relative and absolute paths with the `import()` function, but neither seem to work. The documentation doesn’t provide clear guidance on how to handle public assets without importing them as ES modules.

Is there a way to dynamically import these images based on the `coinSymbol` value in Remix V2?

*In the following code examples, I am trying to access an image inside the 30x30 folder based on a value the component receives*

Here's the function I've written to handle dynamic imports of icons based on a `coinSymbol` value:

```
function useImportIcon(coinSymbol: string): [IconSrc, ImportError] {
  const [iconSrc, setIconSrc] = useState<IconSrc>(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState<ImportError>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    import(`../../../assets/images/coins/30x30/${coinSymbol}.png`) // or `~/assets/....`
      .then((iconModule) => setIconSrc(iconModule.default))
      .catch((error: Error) => {
        console.error(`Failed to load icon for ${coinSymbol}:`, error);
        setError(error);
      });
  }, [coinSymbol]);

  return [iconSrc, error];
}
```

Whenever I attempt to load an icon, I receive the following error:

`Failed to load icon for BTC: TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:3000/assets/images/coins/30x30/BTC.png`

However, this URL indeed doesn't seem to correspond to the actual location of my assets. My folder structure is as follows:

```
  .
└── assets
    └── images
        └── coins
            └── 30x30
                ├── 1INCH.png
                ├── AAVE.png
                ├── ACA.png
                ├── ACH.png
                ├── ACM.png
                ├── ADA.png
                ├── ADX.png
                ├── BTC.png
            ├── coins-big.css
            ├── coins-big@2x.png
            ├── coins-small.css
            └── coins-small@2x.png
```

As far as the path, I've tried multiple things, but without any success. A few of the different paths I tried

```
await import(`~/assets/images/coins/30x30/${coinSymbol}.png`)
await import(`/assets/images/coins/30x30/${coinSymbol}.png`)
await import(`assets/images/coins/30x30/${coinSymbol}.png`)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remix uses esbuild to import non-code files. These import loaders are designed to copy the file to the `/public/build/_assets` folder with a filename hash. The import then returns this new file path. This is all done at compile time.

If you want to do this at runtime, just copy all the images to the `/public/images` folder. Then, you can simply generate the URL.

> NOTE: all files in the `/public` folder are relative to the root URL `/`

```js
let imageUrl = `/images/coins/30x30/${coinSymbol}.png`
return <img src={imageUrl} />
```

Comment: This solution works well, thank you. Initially, I considered handling this with dynamic imports. I'm curious if that approach is feasible and whether it offers any advantages, especially when working with files such as images or SVGs.